# How to run event implementation from other event condition

Tags: c#, events, process, keydown

I'm wondering, if is it possible to run `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)`   event process without pressing on enter, correctly to say without event condition itself.

The only way I know to get result, which can be useful  if implemented, is to locate content of condition in function, but I'm asking if it is possible other way.

From textBox2_TextChanged event condition to get implementation of `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) event` of `textBox1_KeyDown` with entering of exist text and containing process implementation?

For example:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
   /// code  

   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)  
   {
      label1.Text = ("text inserted"); 
   }
}
```

and desired result is to call `(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)` implementation with `label1.Text = ("text inserted");` from `textBox1_KeyDown` in `textBox2_TextChanged` here:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (x > 0)
    {
       /// here I want implement if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) from code above with label1.Text = ("text inserted");      
    }
}
```

Comment: The better approach is to move the work into a separate function and call that new function from each of your event handlers.  That's really the right way to solve this type of problem.  It's more readable and more maintainable, and provides better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can like this

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            label1.Text = ("text inserted");
        }

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KeyEventArgs ev = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Enter);
        textBox1_KeyDown(sender, ev);
    }
```